# Not able get all subsets of a list in prolog using subset/2

Tags: prolog, logic

This seems to be working fine:

```
?- subset([1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).
true.
?- subset([1, 2], [1, 4, 2, 3]).
true.
```

But I'm not able to get all such possible subsets using the same format:

```
?- subset(X, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).
ERROR: No rule matches lists:subset(_3308,[1,2,3,4,5])
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [10] lists:subset(_3390,[1,2|...])
ERROR:    [9] toplevel_call(user:user: ...) at c:/program files/swipl/boot/toplevel.pl:1158
```

I'm new to prolog, isn't this how you ask it to find you values? what am I missing here?

Comment: That is specific to SWI. Use [that](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/dialect/sicstus/lists.pl?show=src#sublist/2) definition instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this definition:

```
sub_set([], []).
sub_set( S, [X|Xs]) :-
    sub_set(Ys, Xs),
    (   S = Ys
    ;   S = [X|Ys]  ).
```

Example:

```
?- sub_set(S, [1,2,3]).
S = [] ;
S = [1] ;
S = [2] ;
S = [1, 2] ;
S = [3] ;
S = [1, 3] ;
S = [2, 3] ;
S = [1, 2, 3].
```